# KB4471332 fails with 0x800f0922, EFI partition is over 500MB

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I'm having trouble installing Windows 1809 update KB4471332, it's failing with the error 0x800f0922.

Having done some googling and searching here, many of the suggested solutions involve ensuring the EFI partition is 500MB or more. I encountered a similar issue a while ago and in doing so rebuilt the EFI partition (I had a drive clone gone bad, only the data partition was copied!) and resized it to make sure it was over 500MB. Since then I've had no issues. This is a 'repair install' also, having run the 1809 ISO a few weeks ago. (Having had no issues installing updates since. This is the first problem I'm having with this install)

[Partition layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YLvE.png)

I've also tried resetting Windows Update via the troubleshooter and clearing the softwaredistribution folder then attempting the update once more. I've even downloaded the standalone updater from the update catalogue. Each time it installs, reboots, gets to around 96% 'configuring update' after the reboot then says it was unable to complete the update and is reverting changes. Upon checking event viewer the error 0x800f0922 is logged.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: So, it appears that it's _just_ KB4471332 that faces the issue, I used the Windows Update MiniTool to install other updates except that and they installed just fine... Curious

Comment: I don't think this is your problem, but you might want to double-check: https://superuser.com/a/1383752/96662

Answer (score 1):

no space in system reserved partition will cause 0x800f0922 error code when update. You could remove some 3rd party software log from system reserved partition to release disk space. But not every 0x800f0922 error code is related with the same reason. We also need to check the real reason through CBS.log file. The details will recorded in the log such as (ERROR_DISK_FULL) or Error HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND)  and others.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not entirely sure how to interpret the CBS.log. I've uploaded it to google drive, if somebody would be able to take a look that would be great! [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YWEFHPHzmswq0d6KYos-tZIhdtuMa_c9/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

If your partition style is **GPT** then please consider the following:

The error code 0x800f0922 is mainly due to your *System Reserved Partition* being full or insufficient in size. While Windows recommends the **max size** to be 500 MB, it is **HIGHLY ADVISED not to tamper with the size as it could lead to serious bootup issues in case you mess up.**

Here's what I did [Steps 1-4] and how I would proceed if it was not working [Step 5-11]:

1. Run Disk Clean-up and safely delete delivery optimization and thumbnails files [I liberated almost 1 GB with this].
2. Run services.msc and make App Readiness service Automatic and restart the service.[Optionally you can follow the same steps for Background Intelligent Transfer Service and Windows Update Service]
3. Temporarily Disable your Domain, Public and Private network Firewall Settings.[Remember to re-enable them later]
4. Restart your system to see if it works.
5. If Step 4 is not working, then try repairing the rebuilt performance counter setting via `https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/error-0x800f0922-installing-windows-update-windows-10/#:~:text=The%20Windows%20Update%20error%200x800F0922,is%20less%20than%2015%20MB.` [You may need to run the commands TWICE to fix any command-line errors]. Restart your system to see if it works.
6. If Step 5 is not working, then try net stop wuauserv,  net stop bits, net stop dosvc followed by net start wuauserv,  net start bits, net start dosvc RESPECTIVELY, on your CMD in Administrator mode. Restart your system to see if it works.

> > **BACKUP YOUR FILES NOW SINCE THE NEXT STEPS CAN BE POTENTIALLY HAZARDOUS FOR YOUR SYSTEM.**

7. If Step 6 is not working, then try temporarily disable secure boot on your BIOS settings. Restart your system to see if it works. [Remember to re-enable secure boot once your issue is solved]
8. If Step 7 not working, try using cmd commands DISM (scanhealth,checkhealth restorehealth) and scf/scannow. Wait for them to complete. Restart your system to see if it works.
9. If Step 8 is not working, try manually downloading the faulty update from Windows Update Catalog and install them. Restart your system to see if it works.
10. If Step 9 is not working, try resizing the System Reserved Partition [**PROCEED WITH EXTREME CARE**] using either CMD via `https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/-we-couldn-t-update-system-reserved-partition-error-installing-windows-10-46865f3f-37bb-4c51-c69f-07271b6672ac` or making use of Windows partition tools like EaseUS, MiniTool, Gparted, and AOMEI among others.
11. If Step 10 is not working, then please either seek the help of a system administrator most notably, among IT professionals, or consult Microsoft forums, before any 'last resort' attempts of Resetting your Windows Installation.

Hoping this helps!