# Windows Update - Error Code 0x800f0922

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, windows-10-v21h2

So I ran into an interesting problem today that I had not seen before, and it took a while before I realized what was causing it.

I have been unable to install any update for about a month, distributed through Windows Update.  I never actually checked on the status of the updates and assumed the updates had successfully been installed.

[image]

If anyone is interested in the Windows Update Log for the unsuccessful attempt, you can find that [here](https://pastebin.com/7K9aV93W).  Due to the length, it is far too large to provide in the body of this question.  While [KB4471332 fails with 0x800f0922, EFI partition is over 500MB](https://superuser.com/questions/1383124/kb4471332-fails-with-0x800f0922-efi-partition-is-over-500mb/1643260#1643260) has had an answer submitted, it was never accepted, and I already ruled it out as a possible solution.

Other existing questions ask about this particular error code.  However, none of them had accepted answers.  Of the questions that do exist with answers, most of them suggest reinstalling .NET Framework 3.5, which I immediately ruled out as not being a solution.  As to the reasons I ruled out these solutions, I looked at the Windows Update Log that I generated, and no errors surrounding an inability to update the EFI partition or the .NET Framework 3.5 were found in the error log.  Some answers suggested performing a repair install.  I also ruled that solution since that isn't a solution to this error code. I saw some other solutions that involved wiping Edge, I have no idea what Edge has to do with this particular error code, so I also ruled out that as a possible solution

So what exactly is causing any update to generate the error code 0x800f0922, and how do I fix my system so I can install updates without performing a repair install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the Windows Update log that I generated, I ran the Windows Update troubleshooter.  Of course, it detected no issues, despite there being an issue.  I then remembered that I used a feature within Killer Intelligence Center called GameFast, which stopped a large number of running services.  I also recalled that while this feature was enabled, the application itself crashed, and when I ultimately attempted to disable it, services that were stopped and disabled remained in this state.

Ultimately I thought I had restated all the services, but after researching 0x800f0922, I discovered one vital service was still disabled.  The service is called App Readiness, and despite its description within Services, it is essential to Windows Update successfully install updates.  It also is required for Microsoft Store to install application updates.

It appears I might have had a pending update waiting to be installed when this service was initially disabled, so when I attempted to install the pending update, it failed.

The ultimate fix to my issue was to enable and set to Automatic, the App Readiness service, and reattempt the installation of the failing updates.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error when installing [kb5012170](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/kb5012170-security-update-for-secure-boot-dbx-august-9-2022-72ff5eed-25b4-47c7-be28-c42bd211bb15) on my Windows 10 21H2 ([19044.2130](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/october-11-2022-kb5018410-os-builds-19042-2130-19043-2130-and-19044-2130-6390f057-28ca-43d3-92ce-f4b79a8378fd)).
My OS build should already include that security update, but the corporate tools still want to install it.

It turned out, that it was necessary to manually suspend bitlocker before running the kb5012170 installer (most updates do that automatically). After that, it marked itself "installed successfully" in just a second.

In general, AFAIU, `0x800f0922` is just a general "unknown error", commonly specific to a particular update. So the "magic fix" is probably update-specific as well.