# Botched Windows 11 Update Keeps Trying (and Failing) to Reinstall After Every Reboot

Tags: windows-update, windows-11

2022-06 Cumulative Update for Windows 11 (KB5014668):

[image]

failed to install on my machine and now every time I reboot it keeps trying to reinstall but failing causing the computer to reboot twice before it loads the OS:

[image]

I disabled automatic updates but this issue persisted.

How do I stop Windows from trying to reinstall this update?

EDIT 1 2022-06-29: I set the "AppReadiness" service to Automatic, started the service and tried the updated again but it failed again.

I uploaded my Windows Update Log to Pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/Gu3rZQ7j).

I am seeing a bunch of entries like this one:

*FAILED* [8024000E] file = onecore\enduser\windowsupdate\client\lib****.cpp, line = xx but I don't see anything more descriptive...

EDIT 2 2022-06-29:

Here is additional troubleshooting I tried without any luck:

- Followed the steps to [Reset Windows Update components manually](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/windows-update-resources).
- Used "Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool" to perform component cleanup as described [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/when-trying-to-install-updates-from-windows-update-you-might-receive-updates-failed-there-were-problems-installing-some-updates-but-we-ll-try-again-later-with-errors-0x80073701-0x800f0988-e74b3505-f054-7f15-ec44-6ec0ab15f3e0) by issuing the following command in the command prompt `dism /online /cleanup-image /startcomponentcleanup`and command `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`as suggested in the comments.

Comment: [I would check the Windows Update History to confirm if the update hasn’t been failing due to a required service being enabled and running](https://superuser.com/questions/1722290/windows-update-error-code-0x800f0922). You should provide a screenshot of your windows  update history by editing your question. **The behavior you describe is exactly what I experienced.**

Comment: Try cleaning the Component Store [`%WinDir%\WinSxS`]: `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup ; Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`, then run the Windows Update troubleshooter

Comment: That is what I had in my answer  except there are far fewer steps in Repair than the Troubleshooter .  I posted what actually works.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem with KB5034121.
The solution that worked for me was using the [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows11) to update Windows 11.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1236575)