# Windows 10 update KB5016616 and KB5017308 hang on reboot after install

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I'm trying to update to the latest Win10 update released on 8/8/22.  Ever since that update was downloaded the machine hangs on the required reboot after the install.  I have disabled updates until I can find a fix. I've tried to download the update and install manually but get the same results.  Other updates, such as .NET, download and installed fine.  Once the machine hangs it has to be rebooted 2 times to get to the automatic roll back.  At least that works for now.

There is an error in the event log but I think its from the install abort from a forced shutdown.

Installation Failure: Windows failed to install the following update with error 0x800F0845: 2022-08 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 21H2 for x64-based Systems (KB5016616).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In order to diagnose this issue we need the [Windows Update log](https://superuser.com/questions/1536806/where-are-really-the-log-files-to-debug-when-a-windows-10-update-fails/1536813#1536813).  I would run the Windows Update troubleshooter by running `ms-settings:troubleshoot`.  [If that fails I would download the update, and install it manually, after you publish the logs to Windows Update.](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB5016616)

Comment: "Once the machine hangs it has to be rebooted 2 times to get to the automatic roll back." - This is normal, when an update cannot be installed, you must identify the reason it cannot be installed. [Make sure the `App Readiness` service is running](https://superuser.com/questions/1722290/windows-update-error-code-0x800f0922).  I would also run `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth` as an Administrator

Comment: How should I post the update log?  App Readiness is set to Manual and not running.  I downloaded the update and tried it manually multiple times but it fails the same way ans the auto update.  I ran the trouble shooter multiple times, it turned on BITS and the update services the first time but is not of any help after that.

Comment: Set it to automatic, why do you have services that shouldn’t be set to manual (connected to Windows Update), set to manual?

Comment: @Ramhound on Windows VLSC/MAK version from MS download center, default status for App Readiness is manual, and there are no documentation why it's manual... it's a fresh ISO from VLSC/Licensing portal ISO.

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto - I speak from experience, that service if not running, will cause issues with Windows Update.

Comment: I've been conversing in another thread and apparently this problem is wide spread and it might have something to do with the machine being upgraded in place from Win7 to Win10.  This is the other thread:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-10-update-kb5016616-hangs-on-reboot-after/8722de52-46ca-44ed-af4f-281b9f57a225?messageId=8d043784-ca62-40e7-a6e5-fb4423661f77&page=1

Comment: @Ramhound I tried with App readiness on automatic and the update fails the same way as it has been.  Check out the thread above.  This is a a big problem for a lot of people.  
Heads up -- the next cumulative update, KB5017308, fails the same way also.

Comment: @glez - I have spent literally hundreds of hours researching this topic, there is absolutely no difference between an installation that has been upgraded to Windows 10 and a Windows 10 installation that was directly installed. There is a single registry that does exist but your problem has absolutely both to do with that key. I asked for the Windows Update logs more than a month ago. I have no doubt the cause for the update failure is contained within that log.

Comment: @Ramhound I asked you how you wanted me post the log file when you asked for it.  Have you checked out the other thread?

Comment: KB-5017308, also a cumulative update, fails the same way.  I updated the title of this post.

Comment: @glez - Yes; I have

Comment: How can I get the logs to you?  There's not an upload process here.

Comment: I did some more digging.  I cleared the Win Update log folder and tried a manual install of KB-5017308.  It failed but I have the update logs.  I'm not an expert but I see the same Windows Defender update being installed at least a dozen times, KB-2267602.  Its the last thing that happened before I did the double reboot.

ThreadID="1,400" Info="Deserialized installable update Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Version 1.375.515.0), UpdateID = {B7EFB2DC-2B14-4D03-83E9-1C2FBAFB43E7.200}, CallbackInfo cookie length = 0"